# unable to compile r markdown code

Tags: r, knitr

I like to use knitr to create reports. I installed knitr and when I try to combile to pdf, I get this error:

```
no tex installation detected. please install tex before compiling.
```

Where do I get this? Is tex an r package? I am on windows?

Comment: http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/authoring/overview ; "To use Sweave and knitr to create PDF reports, you will need to have LaTeX installed on your system. LaTeX can be installed following the directions on the LaTeX project page."; http://www.latex-project.org/ftp.html

Comment: I understand why this question was downvoted, but I think it's a good one. The OP began with a faulty model of how `TeX`, `r` and `knitr` work together, asked, got a good answer and immediately implemented it and accepted it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TeX is not an R package. TeX is a typesetting system (with considerable online presence, including its own StackExchange site). If you are on Windows (which, if you have to ask, you probably are), consider the MiKTeX distribution: http://www.miktex.org/